# Correct Kent C. Dodds' spelling in blogpost and banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

I know, I know, it's just a teeny, tiny thing but as we all here aim for correctness, I thought I would point out a little mistake that apparently managed to sneak into the [blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/19/podcast-a-few-of-our-favorite-things-about-react/) and banner.

On Kent's [website](https://kentcdodds.com) which you linked in the post, you will find a link to the [info page](https://kentcdodds.com/info) which also includes a section on how to spell his name.
Under the section "This is ***not*** correct:" we find this entry amongst others:

> Kent C Dodds (missing the .)

which is precisely how the name is spelt twice in the blogpost as well as in the podcast announcing banner on top of each page on SO.

Surely Kent would appreciate the correction to his name being made :)

To try and please meta folks, I drew some freehand red circles around the problem areas:

[image: blog post mistakes]

[image: banner mistake]

Comment: The dot is still there. It was just added to the set of Dodds for reasons of efficiency.

Comment: Maybe he's a C programmer and C is really his middle name?

Comment: We will never know but if he insists on the period, who are we to judge? @Lundin

Comment: "Kent C". Can't see? Maybe it's a codename.

Comment: @Gimby Kent C Dodds -> can't see dots? dot??....

Comment: @Gimby obviously doesn't C#

Comment: I don't know how to React to this.

Comment: Based on current events, not calling someone what they want to be called may not be such a teeny tiny thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the report (and attention to the details)! We fixed the typos and updated the blog post.